# Mysql trigger on insert based on number match

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, insert

I am using MySQL and I want a trigger on my table sms after every insert which will do the following:

Update sms set provider = 'gp' where number like '88017%';
Update sms set provider = 'blink' where number like '88019%';
Update sms set provider ='robi' where number like '88018%';
Update sms set provider = 'airtel' where number like '88016%';
Proivder is varchar and number is integer.

Based on the number (integer) field I would like to update the provider(string) field.

This is a for a sms gateway so based on the carrier I would like to setup different routes.

Comment: Thats gonna be very inefficient and prone to performance issues depending on how man rows can ever be INSERTED at a time, you should look into doing that as part of the INSERT statement instead with the values precalculated or JOINED via some other table. Also just a general thing at least in the US for cellphones: number ranges are not specific to carriers, people can switch carriers and take their number with them (we deal with this ourselves in one of our major applications)

Comment: This is your third attempt at asking the question; you have not provided the requested information for us to help you.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147115/multiple-queries-on-insert-trigger & http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146776/trigger-on-insert-based-on-number-match

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been asked 2x: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147115/multiple-queries-on-insert-trigger and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146776/trigger-on-insert-based-on-number-match (thanks Rick James)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan on using arithmetic operations on your data, save them as string, not as number. This is especially true for phone numbers (think of leading zeros).

And doing several update operations is more expensive than doing a single, more complex update. So create a new table with the corresponding prefixes and create an INSERT trigger. In case all your prefixes are of the same length it could be like `SET NEW.provider = (SELECT provider FROM prefixes WHERE prefix = LEFT(NEW.number,5)` )

Comment: So far I have tried this and this works , but is this the best way of doing this
DROP TRIGGER
IF EXISTS upd_gp;

DELIMITER $$


CREATE TRIGGER upd_gp BEFORE INSERT ON `test` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF (NEW.num LIKE '88017%') THEN

SET NEW.provider = 'gp' ;
END
IF ;
IF (NEW.num LIKE '88019%') THEN

SET NEW.provider = 'blink' ;
END
IF ; END$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Counterquestion: Would you enjoy recreating the trigger every time the provider prefixes change?